# Input lag issue on On-Screen keyboard in Windows 10 Enterprise 2016

Tags: windows, xamarin, memory, uwp, keyboard

Experiencing on-screen keyboard issues, specifically with UWP applications. **This problem is not consistent across all devices; only some are affected. Interestingly, the issue occurs exclusively within my UWP app and not across all applications on those devices.** When the problem arises in my UWP app, I've observed that closing and reopening the app doesn't resolve the issue. However, when I switch to Notepad and use the same on-screen keyboard, there is no delay, and Notepad functions properly. **On the first screen the there was no input lag, after entered into 2nd screen I'm start to face this issue**

I have already ensured that the correct settings are in place and that keyboard drivers are up to date. Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I am reaching out to the community for advice or experiences that could help troubleshoot this problem more effectively. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide more a [mcve] to help us further check the problem for you?